# Run Microsoft SCCM Remote Control Viewer on Client Machines?

Tags: remote-desktop, sccm, remote-desktop-services, system-center

I've install SCCM 2012 on a server and have successfully used the Remote Control option to take control of a system I've setup to be managed by SCCM. Now, I don't want to have to log in to a server every time I want to access this client...is there a way to run the Remote Control Viewer client on my desktop OS so I can take remote control of systems rather than having to remote in from the server? This seems like very basic functionality...but I haven't been able to figure it out thus far.

Comment: If you run the SCCM installer on your desktop, you should have the option to install only the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run the SCCM installer on your workstation, choose the option to **Install Configuration Manager console**. Now you can run the console from your own workstation instead of using remote desktop to the server.

This screenshot is from Beta 1, but it looks the same.

[image: SCCM Install Splash]